# Bootstrap Modal appearing on right side of screen beacuse of css stylesheet link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have this code that shows a bootstrap modal:

```js
function showmodal() {
  $("#ModalMSJ").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" name="btnOcultarEncabezadoFactura" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="OcultarEncabezadoFactura" onclick="showmodal()" data-row-id="0">Show Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalMSJ" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight: bold; color:black;" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;" id="MSJ">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is this part:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I remove that part the modal works as expected. But the problem is I need to have those css stylesheet. How can I solve this?

Result output:

[image: Modal]

Comment: it seems like you have two bootstraps.css being loaded into your code... in the first line and fifth line.

Comment: that was the problem...I did not noticed that! But How can I have more than 1 bootstraps.css?

Comment: why would you want to have more than one bootstrap? Pick a version that best suits your needs, probably 3.3.7 or 4.0, and use it, have more than one will probably cause issues and conflicts